# changing screen length and height

Tags: 13.10, resolution, screen, tv

i have a Samsung notebook which has a 1600x900 resolution screen, however when i connect it to a 1920x1080 TV and select show only TV screen is not being fitting properly and i cannot see the status bar and program bar at the left properly. Setting that was possible with an Intel software but I couldn't find any program to do that. I have tried to set it from system settings but no chance, can you help?

---

tried changing resolutions and drivers and nothing change i can't see status bar at all and i can see only half of unity at the left!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume there's a shortcut for external monitor connection. Usually it toggles between different modes (builtin only, clone, 2 desktops, external only).

Do this until you got clone mode and open the System Settings.

If you can, change the resolution of the external monitor to its correct values. If not, check whether the external monitor is set up correctly.

Comment: i can change the resolution easily, however when i chose external only it doesn't fit correctly, i was able to set that in windows by intel's softwere, clone works, double works, problem is only in external only